# Fermi gas model nucleus

Tags: many-body

I was trying to figure out the solution to exercise 2.7 on Quantum theory of many particles systems by Fetter & Walecka, it asks to model the nucleus as a degenerate non-interacting Fermi gas. Part d of this question is as follows:

If each nucleon is considered to be moving in a constant potential of depth
$V_0$, how large must $V_0$ be?

We only have the following information regarding to model:

The radius of a nucleus with $A$ nucleons is given by $R = r_0A^{\frac{1}{3}}$  with $r_0=
1.2\times10^{-13}cm$

I can't think of an answer other than "At least as large as fermi energy" since I don't see any other way a fermi gas approximation leads to a quantification of a potential well. It seems like in a fermi gas model the confinement to a volume is given and how exactly it is achieved is irrelevant, it could just be an infinite potential well and the model would be exactly the same?

Answer (score 1):

The question is essentially the basic QM problem about the number of levels in a finite potential well, since you cannot put more than one fermion in each state (actually two fermions, if we allow for spin degeneracy - I suppose F&W treat neutrons and protons as the same type of fermions, so we need not to account for isospin here. We thus want to have at least $A/2$ bound states.)

Comment: But isn't this just a lower bound? Which probably translates to somewhere around fermi energy?

Comment: *lower bound* is what they ask un the problem ("how large $V_0$ must be"). Fermi energy is the energy up to which the states are filled - essentially, this is what you need to find, it is the same as $V_0$ (up to a constant/sign).